# summing up number of angular.foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I'm trying to sum ups a few numbers in what should be a simple function. I iterate through my list of numbers and can see form the log that I am seeing each number.

Then I have the following where I have a var that holds the sum and should return it.

But nothing happens!

Here is the code:

```
  angular.extend(self, {

    getTotalGood : function(){
      var total = 1;
      angular.forEach( self.myproducts, function( value, key ){
        console.log(key + ' : ' + value.product.cost);
        total = value.product.cost;
      })
      return total;
    }

  })

  self.getTotalGood();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method like below:

```
 getTotalGood : function(){
  var total = 0;
  angular.forEach( self.myproducts, function( value, key ){
    console.log(key + ' : ' + value.product.cost);
    total += value.product.cost;
  })
  console.log("total: " + total);
  return total;
}
```